# Viewmodel after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

My page accepts a viewmodel on HttpGet. When i submit the form my HttpPost decorated method binds to that model and all is dandy... i can use the model data to save.

My problem is:
Not all values from the original model is passed to the post, only the form fields.

Is there a way to pass the original model to the post method, and only updating the properties that was updated by the form?

I know i can use hidden fields to accomplish this, but the View Model is complex and has nested classes, so mapping it all up will be a pain. can i achieve this in a easier way

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only values that are part of the html `Form` will bound back on the post. If you need all the values from the original model

- you can include them as hidden fields when doing the Get which will be bound to the model when Posted; or
- using the model ID (which I assume is present) make a call the DB to get the relevant fields and rehydrate your object.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the JavascriptSerializer to first serialize the VM and then save it in a hidden field. You could then create the ViewModel again by deserializing the field and then apply the posted values from the string in the hidden field.

If you bind to the VM you can first deserialize to it's original state and then use the TryUpdate method of the controller to overwrite those values with the posted values.